# Convert Object to List

Tags: c#, linq, list, object

I want convert object to list of myclass, which object  is return from linq query.

```
object list = detailManager.GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat(oMutabakat, true);
List<CurrentAccount> accountList = ??
```

GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat method like this;

```
public object GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat(Mutabakat mutabakat, bool Gonderen)
{
    var detayIdList = this.Context.MutabakatDetay.Where(s => s.MutabakatId == mutabakat.MutabakatId).Select(s => s.MutabakatDetayId).ToList();

    var CariEkstreList =         
        (from ekstre in this.Context.CariHesapEkstre
        join detay in this.Context.MutabakatDetay on ekstre.MutabakatDetayId equals detay.MutabakatDetayId
        where detayIdList.Contains(ekstre.MutabakatDetayId.Value) && ekstre.GonderenMukellefFirmaId == mutabakat.GonderenMukellefFirmaId
        select new 
        {
            MutabakatDetayId = ekstre.MutabakatDetayId,
            MutabakatVar = ekstre.MutabakatVar,
            AlanFirmaId = ekstre.AlanFirmaId,
            GonderenMukellefFirmaId = ekstre.GonderenMukellefFirmaId,
            KayitTarihi = ekstre.KayitTarihi,
            DonemYil = ekstre.DonemYil,
            DonemAy = ekstre.DonemAy,
            Degistirildi = ekstre.Degistirildi,
            CariHesapEkstreId = ekstre.CariHesapEkstreId,
            AktaranKullaniciId = ekstre.AktaranKullaniciId,
            AktarimId = ekstre.AktarimId,
            AktarimTarihi = ekstre.AktarimTarihi,
            BakiyeTur = ekstre.BakiyeTur,
            BelgeNo = ekstre.BelgeNo,
            BelgeTarihi = ekstre.BelgeTarihi,
            BelgeTur = ekstre.BelgeTur,
            IslemTarihi = ekstre.IslemTarihi,
            ParaBirimi = ekstre.ParaBirimi,
            TLTutar = ekstre.BakiyeTur == "B" ? ekstre.TLTutar * -1 : ekstre.TLTutar,
            Tutar = ekstre.BakiyeTur == "B" ? ekstre.Tutar * -1 : ekstre.Tutar
        }).ToList();

    return CariEkstreList;
}
```

Comment: `.ToList();` in case that `GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat` doesn't retrurn `IEnumerable<CurrentAccount>` you have to add `Select` i.e. `.Select(item => GetAccountFromItem(item)).ToList();`

Comment: How `GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat` is declared? Is there any reason to assign its result to `object` variable?

Comment: Is the object a list of CurrentAccount? if so cast directly cast it

Comment: try `List<CurrentAccount> accountList = (List<CurrentAccount>)list;`

Comment: Yes i have a reason return to assing its result to object. object. Where i tried cast like this, returns an error.

Comment: what is the error you get when you try to cast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone,  i solved my problem with using reflaction. 
firstly, object casted to IList

```
List<CariHesapEkstre> senderExtractList = GetExtractList((IList)detayManager.GetMutabakatDetayListByMutabakat(oMutabakat, true));
private List<CariHesapEkstre> GetExtractList ( IList tempList )
{
    List<CariHesapEkstre> returnList = new List<CariHesapEkstre>();

    foreach ( var item in tempList )
    {
        CariHesapEkstre extract = new CariHesapEkstre();
        foreach ( PropertyInfo prop in item.GetType().GetProperties() )
        {
            foreach ( PropertyInfo prop2 in extract.GetType().GetProperties() )
            {
                if ( prop2.Name == prop.Name )
                {
                    prop2.SetValue(extract, prop.GetValue(item));
                }
            }
        }

        returnList.Add(extract);
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you've come up with your own solution. But I feel obligated to say that you better not do this. Reflection is a heavyweight operation - and you are using it with triple for loops. Even if this is working it does not mean it is the correct way. You can go from point A to B with an excavator or with a car. Which one makes more sense?

Comment: so, what is your suggestion?

Comment: You can check the answer I have provided. I've updated the code too.

Comment: Okay thank you :) but it doesn' t work for my case. I know, method returns  List instead of object. Bu it is generic. My question was how does object convert to list of a class. Thats all.

Answer (score 3):

It *depends* on what `list` actually is:

A) if `detailManager.GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat(oMutabakat, true)` returns `IEnumerable<CurrentAccount>` then all you have to do is to add `.ToList()`:

```
   List<CurrentAccount> accountList = detailManager
     .GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat(oMutabakat, true)
     .ToList();
```

B) if `detailManager.GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat(oMutabakat, true)` returns `IEnumerable<SomeObject>` and `SomeObject` *can be cast* to `CurrentAccount` then

```
   List<CurrentAccount> accountList = detailManager
     .GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat(oMutabakat, true)
     .OfType<CurrentAccount>()
     .ToList();
```

C) Finally, in the *general case* you have to implement `.Select`:

```
   List<CurrentAccount> accountList = detailManager
     .GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat(oMutabakat, true)
     .Select(item => GetAccountFromItem(item)) //TODO: implement Select
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things I can say,

What does your method `GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat` return? Does it have to be `object`?

As its name implies - if a methods name is `Get...List` I would expect it to return a list, not an object. If you can, first change that behaviour then you'll be ok.

If that method is written by someone else(that you cannot change the behaviour) then you should play with casting operations as the others suggest, but you can only do this if the underlying object is really of type `List<CurrentAccount>`.

And if the underlying object is not even of type `List<CurrentAccount>` then you should learn what the object structure is(another class, anonymous object, or dynamic) then we can work something out.

**After Update**

With the update to your question I can see that you are returning a list of anonymous objects. But isn't it actually `CurrentAccount`?

So if you select it as following:

```
public List<CariHesapEkstre> GetMutabakatDetailListByMutabakat ( Mutabakat mutabakat, bool Gonderen )
{
    var detayIdList = this.Context.MutabakatDetay.Where(s => s.MutabakatId == mutabakat.MutabakatId).Select(s => s.MutabakatDetayId).ToList();

    var CariEkstreList =         
        ( from ekstre in this.Context.CariHesapEkstre
            join detay in this.Context.MutabakatDetay on ekstre.MutabakatDetayId equals detay.MutabakatDetayId
            where detayIdList.Contains(ekstre.MutabakatDetayId.Value) && ekstre.GonderenMukellefFirmaId == mutabakat.GonderenMukellefFirmaId

            /// here you only need to use object initializer for CariHesapEkstre like just below
            select new CariHesapEkstre
            {
                MutabakatDetayId = ekstre.MutabakatDetayId,
                MutabakatVar = ekstre.MutabakatVar,
                ...
                Tutar = ekstre.BakiyeTur == "B" ? ekstre.Tutar * -1 : ekstre.Tutar
            } ).ToList();

    return CariEkstreList;
}
```

**Last Update**

I see what you are trying to do, you want a method to do the hardwork for you. So you can check this tool called [automapper](http://automapper.org/). It does what you are trying to do. But still it's a hard work for your code too.

But if you are only trying to convert an object to a list you can use the code below.

```
    public List<CariHesapEkstre> ConvertToDesiredType ( object list )
    {
        return ( (IEnumerable<dynamic>)list ).Select(item => new CariHesapEkstre
        {
            MutabakatDetayId = item.MutabakatDetayId,
            MutabakatVar = item.MutabakatVar,
            ...
        }).ToList();
    }
```